# Accessing WsFederationOptions in .NET Core Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ws-federation, asp.net-authentication

In my web application, I use WS-Fed / AD FS for authentication, to start this up, it basically looks like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-ws-federation-without-aspnet-core-identity

It works fine, but in my application, I would like to access some properties of WsFederationOptions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.wsfederation.wsfederationoptions?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

So far I could not find a way how to do this.

I tried calling `AuthenticationService authenticationService = (AuthenticationService)serviceProvider.GetService<IAuthenticationService>();`, I can see in `authenticationService.Options.Schemes[0].` the correct `DisplayName`, `HandlerType` and `Name` but there are no more properties.

My current workaround is that I remember those properties in a seperate class on Startup, but it would be great to access the properties of this class during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve an `IOptions<WsFederationOptions>` from the service provider, but [depending on your aspnet version](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1312#issuecomment-314790390) you may have to use `IOptionsMonitor<WsFederationOptions>` or `IOptionsSnapshot<WsFederationOptions>` to get the correctly configured instance.